# I can't apply the average() method in the stream

Tags: java, java-stream

I need to find the average of all the student's subjects. the result should be similar to this
Ann 3.5
Kate 4.0
for each student, all his grades in all subjects are added up.
my solution doesn't work, I don't understand why

```
class St3_1 {

private String name;
private Map<String, List<Integer>> marks;


public St3_1(String name, Map<String, List<Integer>> marks) {
    this.name = name;
    this.marks = marks;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public Map<String, List<Integer>> getMarks() {
    return marks;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Map<String, List<Integer>> markAnn = new HashMap<>();
    markAnn.put("Physics", List.of(4, 4, 5));
    markAnn.put("Mathematics", List.of(2, 3, 4));
    markAnn.put("History", List.of(3, 3, 3));

    Map<String, List<Integer>> markKate = new HashMap<>();
    markKate.put("Physics", List.of(1, 2, 3));
    markKate.put("Mathematics", List.of(5, 5, 3));
    markKate.put("History", List.of(4, 2, 5));

    St3_1 [] students = { new St3_1("Ann", markAnn),
                          new St3_1("Kate", markKate)
    };
    Map<String,Double> map = Arrays.stream(students)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(St3_1::getName,
                    x -> x.getMarks().entrySet()
                            .stream()
                            .mapToDouble(Integer::doubleValue)
                            .average()
                            .getAsDouble()
                            )
            );
}
```

}

Comment: In your stream usage, if you mapped your keys to `String`, and your values to `Double`, why would you expect a `Map<String, Integer>`? You definitely can't hold `3.5` in that.

Comment: what is the actual result and the expected result?

Comment: you want the average of each student, or the average of each course, or something else?

Comment: I made a mistake when I wrote Map<String, Integer>. I fixed it on Map<String, Double>, but it still doesn't work.
The result should be as follows: all the student's grades in all subjects are added up and the average grade is found

Comment: `flatMap` the `value` of the entrySet and then perform the everage

Answer (score 1):

You need to collect each student's marks as a `Map<String, Double>`.

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Student {
    public static Function<Map<String, List<Integer>>, Map<String, Double>> averager = (marks) ->
        marks.entrySet()
            .stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    entry -> entry.getKey(),
                    entry -> entry.getValue().stream()
                            .mapToDouble(Integer::doubleValue)
                            .average()
                            .getAsDouble()));

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, List<Integer>> markAnn = new HashMap<>();
        markAnn.put("Physics", Arrays.asList(4, 4, 5));
        markAnn.put("Mathematics", Arrays.asList(2, 3, 4));
        markAnn.put("History", Arrays.asList(3, 3, 3));

        Map<String, List<Integer>> markKate = new HashMap<>();
        markKate.put("Physics", Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));
        markKate.put("Mathematics", Arrays.asList(5, 5, 3));
        markKate.put("History", Arrays.asList(4, 2, 5));

        Student[] students = {
                new Student("Ann", markAnn),
                new Student("Kate", markKate)
        };

        Map<String, Map<String, Double>> averages = Arrays.stream(students)
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Student::getName,
                        student -> averager.apply(student.getMarks())));

        System.out.println(averages);
    }

    public Student(String name, Map<String, List<Integer>> marks) {
        this.name = name;
        this.marks = marks;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Map<String, List<Integer>> getMarks() {
        return marks;
    }

    private String name;
    private Map<String, List<Integer>> marks;
}
```

Output (formatted):

```
{
  Ann = {
    Mathematics = 3.0,
    History = 3.0,
    Physics = 4.333333333333333
  },
  Kate = {
    Mathematics = 4.333333333333333,
    History = 3.6666666666666665,
    Physics = 2.0
  }
}
```

If you want just the overall averages, you can flat-map all the marks:

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Student {
    public static Function<Map<String, List<Integer>>, Double> averager = (marks) ->
        marks.values().stream()
            .flatMap(List::stream)
            .mapToDouble(Integer::doubleValue)
            .average()
            .getAsDouble();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, List<Integer>> markAnn = new HashMap<>();
        markAnn.put("Physics", Arrays.asList(4, 4, 5));
        markAnn.put("Mathematics", Arrays.asList(2, 3, 4));
        markAnn.put("History", Arrays.asList(3, 3, 3));

        Map<String, List<Integer>> markKate = new HashMap<>();
        markKate.put("Physics", Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));
        markKate.put("Mathematics", Arrays.asList(5, 5, 3));
        markKate.put("History", Arrays.asList(4, 2, 5));

        Student[] students = {
                new Student("Ann", markAnn),
                new Student("Kate", markKate)
        };

        Map<String, Double> averages = Arrays.stream(students)
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Student::getName,
                        student -> averager.apply(student.getMarks())));

        System.out.println(averages);
    }

    public Student(String name, Map<String, List<Integer>> marks) {
        this.name = name;
        this.marks = marks;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Map<String, List<Integer>> getMarks() {
        return marks;
    }

    private String name;
    private Map<String, List<Integer>> marks;
}
```

Output (formatted):

```
{
  Ann = 3.4444444444444446,
  Kate = 3.3333333333333335
}
```

Comment: I didn't need the average for each subject separately, but the overall average was for the student Ann=3.4444444444444446, Kate=3.3333333333333335

Comment: @KtoTam updated, see the updated response.

Answer (score 0):

this code works. I forgot to add flatmap

```
Map<String,Double> map = Arrays.stream(students)
                   .collect(Collectors.toMap(St3_1::getName,
                    student -> student.getMarks().entrySet()
                            .stream()
                            .flatMap(z -> z.getValue().stream())
                            .mapToDouble(Integer::doubleValue)
                            .average()
                            .getAsDouble()));
```

Comment: Consider using `#flatMapToDouble`, which would combine the operations of `#flatMap` and `#mapToDouble` above.